# Lightsail Bitnami HTTP-Only Application

Tags: .htaccess, phpmailer, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

HTTP-Only Application in Lightsail seems to not popular.

- Where is right place for the html application;

('**/home/bitnami/projects/myapp**',
'**/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp**',
'**opt\bitnami\apache\htdocs**')

- Where and how locate rule for remove 'myapp' from url ([www.myDomain.com/myapp](http://www.myDomain.com/myapp));
- Where should be 'amazon-ses-smtp-sample.php' and how to prevent them to access from url;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here, you will need to follow the next steps to deploy your custom application on top of a Bitnami solution

- Create the same structure used by Bitnami when installing Bitnami PHP applications. To do this, run these commands:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/myapp
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon /opt/bitnami/myapp
sudo chmod -R g+w /opt/bitnami/myapp
```

- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/myapp-vhost.conf file and add the configuration block shown below:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias *
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/myapp
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/myapp">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/myapp-https-vhost.conf file and add the configuration block shown below:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerAlias *
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/myapp
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/myapp">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

- Restart the Apache server:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You should now be able to access the application at http://SERVER-IP/.

You can find more information about how to deploy the app here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/lamp/administration/create-custom-application-php/

Regarding the amazon-ses-smtp-sample.php file, you will need to add the required rule in the .htaccess file inside the `/opt/bitnami/myapp` directory. Something similar to this

```
<Files "amazon-ses-smtp-sample.php">  
  Require all denied
</Files>
```

Comment: thanks for explanation. Can you please point me where should be located 'amazon-ses-smtp-sample.php'? Actually I put it to myapp folder - when run in terminal php amazon-ses-smtp-sample.php - sent email successfully but it doesn't run like php file when I try to send data from form. POST 200 but this php file doesn't execute proper.

Comment: I replied to your question in the other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66028748/lightsail-bitnami-http-application-send-email. It seems you are not using a Bitnami LAMP solution, you are using MEAN and it does not include PHP.

Comment: @JotaMartos - I followed your steps (along with the official bitnami docs) and the new "myapp" took over the root. I can no longer get to my original wordpress installation. How can one have both under the root? ex. myapp1.com and myapp2.com