# Lightsail Bitnami HTTP Application send email

Tags: php, amazon-s3, bitnami

After created instance MEAN - Bitnami
I successfully following steps in this doc:
[Send an email using SMTP with PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html)

Unfortunately I can't send email from my html form. After submit I see 200 POST in console:

[image]

Seems like php doesn't work at all because I don't see any communication (echo) from php file.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please note that the Bitnami MEAN solution doesn't have PHP installed and Apache doesn't have the libraries to load the PHP code. I understand you should see an error related to that in the Apache's log file (/opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/error_log). Please launch a Bitnami LAMP solution to deploy your custom PHP app on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is because instance MEAN - Bitnami doesn't have php although such information is included in the description:

[image]