# How to install another WordPress setup in a running Bitnami Lightsail instance

Tags: wordpress, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I want to create a staging site for an already running production website which is in WordPress and hosted in AWS Lightsail using the Bitnami LAMP stack.

Is there any way I can install staging WordPress setup in the same instance?

I already checked Bitnami documentation but there is no proper documentation.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, this question was already replied in [this other Stack Overflow ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66012183/4709625)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lightsail Bitnami HTTP-Only Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66006226/lightsail-bitnami-http-only-application)

Comment: @JotaMartos i want to install wordpress setup and guide for that ?

Comment: We do not have a specific guide for WordPress, but you can follow the guide I posted above and deploy the WordPress files inside the folders you are going to create. After that, you will need to connect to the application and configure the database's and user's settings.

Comment: @JotaMartos i am done with setup now i can access site using my ip/folder name is there anydocumentation for how can I link to subdomain?

Comment: You will need to configure the domains in the files you created in the "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts" folder. You will need to set the [ServerName](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servername) and [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) directives.